# Take a Picture or Take from Gallery with Custom Dialog in Android

Tags: android, image, dialog

I was making the dialogue to be able to upload pictures of captured images, or selected from the gallery. But, when it's done to crop the image, my application force close. Here is a method that I developed:

```
 public void uploadPO() {
    ivImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image1);
    etImage1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_image1);
    ivImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image2);
    etImage2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_image2);
    ivImage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image3);
    etImage3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_image3);
    ivImage4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_image4);
    etImage4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_image4);

    final Dialog d = new Dialog(TransDetailActivity.this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable((Color.TRANSPARENT)));
    d.setContentView(R.layout.upload_po);
    final FrameLayout takePicture = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.ambil_gambar);
    final FrameLayout pilihGambar = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.pilih_di_gallery);
    final FrameLayout batal = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.batal);
    final FrameLayout ok = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.OK);
    takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectFrom(PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
        }
    });
    pilihGambar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectFrom(PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    });
    batal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            d.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            labelImage1 = etImage1.getText().toString();
            labelImage2 = etImage1.getText().toString();
            labelImage3 = etImage1.getText().toString();
            labelImage4 = etImage1.getText().toString();

            if (ivImage1 == null || ivImage2 == null || ivImage3 == null || ivImage4 == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Masukkan Empat Gambar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (labelImage1.trim().equals("") || labelImage2.trim().equals("") || labelImage3.trim().equals("") || labelImage4.trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Masukkan Label pada Setiap Gambar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                uploadToApi();
            }
        }
    });
    d.show();
}

private void selectFrom(int from) {
    if (from == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File output = new File(dir, "Avatar" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpeg");
        mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(output);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));
        try {
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, from);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), from);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), from);
        }
    }
}

private void doCrop() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    int size = list.size();
    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+resultCode+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (data != null) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
            doCrop();
        } else if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            doCrop();
        } else if (requestCode == CROP_FROM_CAMERA) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

               /*Picasso.with(this)
                        .load()
                        .transform(new CircleTransform())
                        .into(imageProfile);*/

                if (statusOnUpload == 1) {
                    ivImage1.setImageBitmap(photo);
                } else if (statusOnUpload == 2) {
                    ivImage2.setImageBitmap(photo);
                } else if (statusOnUpload == 3) {
                    ivImage3.setImageBitmap(photo);
                } else if (statusOnUpload == 4) {
                    ivImage4.setImageBitmap(photo);
                }


                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

                if (statusOnUpload == 1) {
                    encodedImageString1 = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    Log.d(TAG, encodedImageString1.toString());
                } else if (statusOnUpload == 2) {
                    encodedImageString2 = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                } else if (statusOnUpload == 3) {
                    encodedImageString3 = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                } else if (statusOnUpload == 4) {
                    encodedImageString4 = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                }

                //Log.i("")

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+encodedImageString+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //DialogDeal dialogDeal=new DialogDeal(EditProfileActivity.this,"imageBase64",encodedImageString,"Cancel");
                //dialogDeal.show();

            } else { //LogManager.logI("extras == null");}}}}
```

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/corner_white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tittle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Upload Purchase Order"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tittle"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/blue" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menu_upload"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/line"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ambil_gambar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ambil Gambar"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/depan"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pilih_di_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Pilih di Gallery"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/line3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/menu_upload"
    android:background="@color/blue" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/gambar_upload"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/line3"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image1"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/addmorepicture"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#809E9E9E"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_image1"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv_image1"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/iv_image1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/iv_image1"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/iv_image1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@id/et_image1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Label Image 1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_image2"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image2"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/addmorepicture" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#809E9E9E"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_image2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv_image2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/iv_image2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/iv_image2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/iv_image2">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@id/et_image2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Label Image 2"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_image3"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image3"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/addmorepicture"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#809E9E9E"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_image3"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_image3"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/iv_image3"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv_image3"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/iv_image3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@id/et_image3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Label Image 3"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_image4"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_image4"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/addmorepicture" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#809E9E9E"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_image4"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/iv_image4"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/iv_image4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/iv_image4"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@id/iv_image4">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@id/et_image3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Label Image 3"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/line4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gambar_upload"
    android:background="@color/blue" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/aksi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/line4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/batal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Batal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line5"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/depan"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/OK"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, this is a sign of error:

```
 02-06 11:01:34.836 11791-11791/blablabla.wkwk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {blablabla.wkwk/codelabs.baf.TransDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3488)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3531)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:156)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at blablabla.wkwk.TransDetailActivity.onActivityResult(TransDetailActivity.java:531)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5371)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3484)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3531) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:156) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For note, i just remake this methode from another class wihtout dialog and that is work. Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: What is line 531 of TransDetailActivity?

Comment: ivImage1.setImageBitmap(photo);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to call `findViewById()` on the Dialog, and put all calls after the call to `d.setContentView()`:

```
 public void uploadPO() {

    final Dialog d = new Dialog(TransDetailActivity.this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable((Color.TRANSPARENT)));
    d.setContentView(R.layout.upload_po);
    final FrameLayout takePicture = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.ambil_gambar);
    final FrameLayout pilihGambar = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.pilih_di_gallery);
    final FrameLayout batal = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.batal);
    final FrameLayout ok = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.OK);

    ivImage1 = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.iv_image1);
    etImage1 = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.et_image1);
    ivImage2 = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.iv_image2);
    etImage2 = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.et_image2);
    ivImage3 = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.iv_image3);
    etImage3 = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.et_image3);
    ivImage4 = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.iv_image4);
    etImage4 = (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.et_image4);
    //........................
```

Comment: Amazing, it's work. Thank you.

I also want to take a picture without crop. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @NurIfAlanFarizi You can just use the initial result in `onActivityResult()`, and process the image immediately instead of making a call to `doCrop()`.